# Select a specific field of a Pd.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I have databases of different sizes! However, I would like to select only the Total column of the Values (red) for a calculation. But since this column is different for the different databases, I cannot write e.g. `df.iloc[5:6, 1:2]`! is there another approach?

[image]

Comment: probably `df.loc[df['ID'].eq('Total'), 'Value']` or `df.loc[df['ID'].eq('Total'), 'Value'].squeeze()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` to access a row specified by its index.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3), index=["a", "b", "Total"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5), index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "Total"])

print(df1.loc["index"].values[0])
print(df2.loc["index"].values[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`df.Value[df.ID=='Total']`

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by explaining what the code does, why it works, linking to external documentation, etc.